# Postgresql - Stuck building a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, function, user-defined-functions, plpgsql

I am a beginner in plpgsql and i am stuck coding a function.
I need a function that does the following:

Giving a table, a id_field in that table and another field in that table it does:

### ORIGINAL TABLE

```
id_field     field_traspose
---------    --------------
    1              A
    1              B
    1              C
    2              A
    3              F
    3              X
```

### RESULT

```
id_field     field_traspose
---------    --------------
    1              A, B, C
    2              A
    3              F, X
```

My attempt:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION traspose(mytable character varying, id_field character varying, field_traspose character varying)
  RETURNS setof RECORD AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    r record;
    result record;
BEGIN

FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT '||id_field||','||field_traspose||'  from '||mytable LOOP

-- Here should go the logic that joins every field_traspose for a same id_field and
--returns the record as one of the returning records (can be many different id_fields)   

RETURN NEXT result;
END LOOP;

RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

I'm stuck at this point.
Regards,

Comment: Cross post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/91171/1822

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for such a function, this is already built-in:

```
select id_field, 
       string_agg(field_traspose, ', ' order by field_traspose) 
from the_table 
group by id_field
order by id_field;
```

Comment: I am in Postgresql 8.4, are you sure this works in 8.4 or only above 9? I am getting a syntax error

Comment: 8.4 is EOL, you need an upgrade. Using array_agg() and array_to_string() can get the same result as string_agg(), it just takes some extra work. As of version 9.0 you can use string_agg() by default, but you could create this function yourself in 8.4